# Zend 2 - set translator text domain for all views

Tags: internationalization, zend-framework2, zend-form

Is there any way of setting translator text domain for all forms elements, in all views ?
For example to get translated my form labels i need to set first text domain:`$this->formLabel()->setTranslatorTextDomain('mytextdomain');`
This code i need to add in every view to translate form label.

So I tried to set the text domain for all views like this:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        // Change the View Helper Text Domain for ALL modules
        'initializers' => array(
            'injectTranslatorTextDomain' => function($helper) {
                if ($helper instanceof TranslatorAwareInterface) {
                    $helper->setTranslatorTextDomain('mytextdomain');
                }
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

It works, but it rewrite the AbstractValidator messages (default validation messages are not translated after i inject translator text domain).

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this question was to add the same "textdomain" for validator and for view helper.Also the "default" can be used for both.